# Product category name on product viewing page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on a [website](http://toolskaart.com). Upon clicking the product it shows all the details of it. But my client want me to show parent category of categroy of the product at top, above the image. Please help me about it. I'm a budding developer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be help someone else.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');?>
<?php $_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');?>
<?php $_category_detail->getName();?>
<?php $_category_detail->getId(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the category data from your product object: `$_product->getCategory()->getName();`. You will have to edit the template at `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`. In the template file look for  `<div class="product-img-box">` and add:

```
        <div class="product-img-box">
            <h4><?php echo $_product->getCategory()->getName(); ?></h4>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Warning: Make sure all your products only belongs to 1 category. Else you should use $_product->getCategoryIds() to have an array of all your categories and make a script to get the better one (not always the biggest id)